# Difference in size of 'P' and "P" in Java

Tags: java

Is there a difference in the size of character constant 'P' and a string containing a single character, say , "P" ? I understand both should be 2 Bytes. Am I right? Is there any way of checking this through code in Java (like the sizeof operator in C)? 
TIA

Comment: Yes. A `String` also has an `int` indicating the `length`. A character is thus *smaller*. Additionally, a `char` is a primitive type, while `String` is a *reference type* (so it's also an `Object`).

Comment: Go through these links : 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-in-java  2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925161/char-vs-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`char` is two bytes. A `String` is an `Object` and therefore its size is really implementation-dependent. A typical implementation includes at least:

- the reference to the object itself (not a part of the object itself, but you can't have an object without at least one reference) which is either a pointer (32 or 64 bits) or a [compressed pointer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html), which could be smaller;
- the reference to the array containing the string, and that's another pointer or a compressed pointer;
- the size of the array, of type `int`, that's 4 more bytes;
- the array itself, which has the size `2` (in bytes);
- whatever else the base class (`Object`) contains, usually it has no explicit fields, but may have "hidden" native implementation data.

So on a 32-bit system that will be 4+4+4+2=14 bytes, adding possible alignment effects, I'd guess it'll be at least 16 bytes. On a 64-bit system with efficiently compressed pointers and small enough heap it'll probably be the same.